# How can I get a user's calendar data from Google Calendar API?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-oauth, google-calendar-api

I'm putting together a web application in which I need to get a list of the user's calendar events. Here are the steps I've followed so far:

1. Setup a project on the google cloud console
2. Enabled the google calendar API for the project
3. Generated the client OAuth ID and secret

When the Google Authentication Popup shows up, all tutorials ask me to log in with the same email I used to set up the project. If I do that, I'm able to view my own calendar events.

However, if I try to log in with a different email ID (let's call this user - X), I can't seem to view X's calendar events and it throws a 403 error.

What steps should I follow to allow any external user to log in and get their calendar info on my web app?

Comment: please edit your question and include the full error message   403 what

Answer (score 0):

> 403: access_denied The developer hasn’t given you access to this app.

[Google OAuth Error 403: access_denied easy fix.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x_NPvk0pk8g)

This is a common error when your application is still in the testing phase. You need to grant your test users permission to access your application.  In google developer console under your consent screen just click add users.

[image]

Note: you can only have 100 test users and you cant remove them once they have been added.